# Why is Chrome reporting a secure / non secure warning when no other browsers aren't?

Tags: security, google-chrome

When I go to our web site through HTTPS mode, Chome is reporting an error saying that the page contains secure and not secure items. However, I used Firebug, Fiddler, and HttpDebuggerPro, all which are telling me that everything is going through HTTPS. Is this a bug in Chrome?

Sorry but I'm unable to give out the actual URL.

Comment: Search the source for "http:"

Comment: Hmmm...it seems to have stopped reporting the error on its own. I'm not too sure what happened, I'm certain it wasn't a caching error though. Maybe Google saw this post, fixed the bug and pushed out an update without me knowing :)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

A bit late to the party here but I've been having issues recently and once I had found a http resource and changed it was still getting the red padlock symbol.  When I closed the tab and opened a new one it changed to a green padlock so I guess Chrome caches this information for the lifetime of the tab

Comment: If you quit chrome (on mac) and then re-open it, at which point it restores the tabs, the red padlock still stays. However closing the tab and creating a new one seems to clear whatever cache it's using

Comment: You can also use a new incognito tab (ctrl+shift+n) for this.

Comment: I also had this problem .. cached. Son of a gun.

New tab fixes issue.

Comment: Was trolling through source and server configs for half an hour...damn , all I had to do was re-open the tab

Comment: Thanks!! I've been going crazy finding out why I couldn't get it to work... tried it in another tab at voilà! So this but is not fixed in the latest Chrome version :(

Answer (score 27):

Current versions of Chrome will show the mixed content's URL in the error console.  Hit CTRL+Shift+J and you'll see text like:

"The page at https://www.fiddler2.com/test/securepageinsecureimage.htm contains insecure content from http://www.fiddler2.com/Eric/images/me.jpg."

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you should flush your browser cache when doing testing like this, because a cached insecure resource request will not hit the network and thus won't be shown by proxy debuggers.

Comment: On Mac CMD+Shift+J is giving me the downloads window. Is there a menu item that does what you're describing?

Comment: Under the wrench menu, Tools -> JavaScript Console does it for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue: Chromium showing the non-secure static files, but when everything was http://.

Just closing the current tab and re-opening the page in another new tab worked, so I think this is a Chromium/Chrome bug.

Cheers,

Diogo

Answer (score 2):

Using Chrome, if you open up the Developer Tools (View > Developer > Developer Tools) and bring up the Console and choose to filter to warnings, you'll see a list of offending URLs.

You'll see something like the following if you do have insecure content

```
The page at https://mysite/ displayed insecure content from http://insecureurl.
```

For the best experience in finding the culprit, you'll want to start your investigation in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that a non-secure URL is referenced but not accessed (e.g. the codebase for a Flash `<object>`).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when Jquery was being executing a a few seconds after page load which added a class containing a non-secure image background. Chrome must continually to check for any non-secure resources to be loaded.

See the code example below. If you had code like this, the green padlock is shown in Chrome for about 5 seconds until the deferred class is applied to the div.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $("#some-div").addClass("deferred")
    }, 5000);


.deferred
{
    background: url(http://not-secure.com/not-secure.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the source of the page for any external objects (scripts, stylesheets, images, objects) linked using `http://...` rather than `https://...` or a relative path. Change the links to use relative paths, or absolute paths without protocol, i.e. `href="/path/to/file"`.

If all that if fine, it could be something included from Javascript. For example, the Google Analytics code uses `document.write` to add a new script to the page, but it has code to check for HTTPS in case the calling page is secure:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

Comment: The SSL certificate had expired on one of my websites so Chrome was giving the Not Secure warning, now the certificate has been renewed and checks ok on two online SSL checkers, shows as secure in Firefox, but still shows Not Secure in Chrome! Clearing the cache using an extension, F5, shift+F5, new tab, new window, none clear the warning. I guess I'll have to wait for Chrome to decide when it wants to update it's information.

Answer (score 0):

On the release of Chrome version 53 on Windows, Google has changed the trust indications to initiate the circle-i. Afterward, Google has announced a new warning message will be issued when a website is not using HTTPS.

> From  2017 January Start, Popular web browser Chrome will begin
>   labeling HTTP sites as “Not Secure” [Which transmit passwords / ask
>   for credit card details]

Answer (score -1):

If all your resources are indeed secure, then it is a bug. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72015 . Luckily it was fixed.

Comment: It was not fixed. And that linked issue is, rather suspiciously, set to private now.