# How can you tell exactly what insecure items are causing a browser to warn about mixed secure and insecure items?

Tags: google-chrome, https

In Firefox, I view my site and get no warnings about insecure mixed content.

Using FireBug, I can see that every request is `https`.

In Chrome, I get the `https` crossed out in the address bar.

[image: Chrome's address bar]

[image: Chrome's error]

I viewed source in Chrome and then ran this regex `/http(?!s)/` but the only things it found were the `href` attributes for some external links and the doc type and `http-equiv` meta tags.

Using Chrome's *Resource Tracking* revealed all requests were `https` too.

This includes Google Analytics, jQuery from Google's CDN and Facebook like scripts.

Is there any specific tool I can use to show non `https` requests, or anything further I can try?

Comment: **48-th version of Chrome** made it [dead simple](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34575110/1090562)

Comment: I know this post is old but in case it helps anyone, there's a Desktop app you can run now to scan and report on mixed content issues found on a site: https://www.ecommerce.co.uk/httpschecker

Comment: @alex: I know this question is pretty old now, but given the slew of new (and possibly better) answers, I just wanted to ping you to have a read through them -- maybe there is a better answer than mine that is deserving of the acceptance.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I will take a look

Answer (score 60):

I found that I get the "mixed content"-warning in Chrome even when there is no mixed content, if *sometime* during the session mixed content was already encountered on the domain.

(Also mentioned here: [Why is Chrome reporting a secure / non secure warning when no other browsers aren't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087591/why-is-chrome-reporting-a-secure-non-secure-warning-when-no-other-browsers-aren))

Comment: Thanks for posting this. This solved my issue actually, knowing that Chrome cache's based on the tab saved me hours. Somewhere on my site there was mixed content and that set off the error for all pages running https...even if there were no http requests.

Comment: That's really annoying.  Just had this issue myself and sure enough, when I opened a new tab and pasted the same url into it I got a green https and lock icon.  Anyone know why chrome does it this way?

Comment: Thanks, still an issue in Chrome 3 years later! Restarting Chrome sorted it.

Comment: Yet another 'thanks' coming from me! Trawling through my code replacing all relative and absolute URLs with https versions to no avail. Then simply copy/pasting the url into a new tab sorted it. Thanks Google! :-\

Answer (score 38):

In Chrome's Developer Tools, the Console tab shows the resources that it won't load because they unsecure.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, its built in to the browser.

Comment: Yes, this is best/easiest answer. Fiddler, et al aren't that useful because you have to sift through a mass of requests.

Comment: This is the best way, because it isn't just resources that cause the problem. I found that a newsletter form that targeted an insecure page also resulted my green bar being broken. I was confused because the Network tab showed all https. The Console tab told me the answer, though.

Answer (score 19):

You can add the "scheme" column to the Chrome developer tools network tab to show which requests were sent over http or https:

1. Press F12 to show the developer tools
2. Switch to the Network tab
3. Right click in the column headers and select "Scheme"
4. Reload the page to show which elements are loaded over http or https

[image: Chrome developer tools, scheme column]

Answer (score 6):

In situations like this where it's helpful to see exactly which protocol is being used to load resources, I would recommend [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) as a browser-agnostic solution that can show you exactly what traffic is occurring on each request.

From the site:

> Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet. Fiddler allows you to inspect all HTTP(S) traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle" with incoming or outgoing data. Fiddler includes a powerful event-based scripting subsystem, and can be extended using any .NET language.

**Edit**: In-browser debugging tools are becoming really good so this third-party tool may not be as useful as it was when this answer was first written.

Answer (score 6):

In **48-th** version of chrome they added a [security panel](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/security-panel). Using it you can quickly identify the mixed content resources:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Open up the Web Inspector and find the yellow triangle (warning) in the top right. Click on it and it will display all security issues.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Why download/use 3rd party tools when you can view the insecure resources from within Chrome?

Comment: This does not actually display the security issues, at least not for me on today's version of Chrome.  I seem to remember these sorts of things appearing as warnings in the console, but that no longer is the case, at least not for my strange situation.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the HttpFox plugin for FireFox?  That'd work, I think.
Among other things, it reports on the URL, Method, Result Code, and bytes of all the assets that a web page requests.  It's what I've used to trap the occasional non-HTTPS graphic, etc.   I'm sure the other suggested tools would do the same...

Comment: Nope, but I'll go check it out now. Thanks.

Comment: Damn, couldn't find any non HTTPS requests with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SslCheck](http://jitbit.com/sslcheck/)

It's a free online tool that crawls a website recursively (following all internal links) and scans for nonsecure includes - images, scripts and CSS.

(disclaimer: I'm one of the developers)

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but I ran across it and had the same issue. I clicked on the Chrome menu (top right corner), scrolled down to Tools> and selected Developer Tools. Clicked on the Console tab and it told me exactly what the problem was... the favicon was served over http, not https, but of course it was not in the page source code. Corrected the problem in my CMS, which loads the favicon without code in the page... and no more error!

Answer (score 0):

Note that 'mixed content' and 'mixed scripting' are detected seperatly. Check this site for the meaning of the icons in Chrome: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/95617?p=ui_security_indicator&rd=1  (click 'see details' link).

Grey icon = mixed content, red icon = mixed scripting.