# Warnings about "Insecure elements" on some HTTPS sites in Chrome but no such elements can be found

Tags: google-chrome, https, web-inspector

I recently installed [Pi-Hole](http://pi-hole.net/) and use it as primary DNS. It works great, the ads disappeared and the Pi's log files are filling up with blocked stuff.

But I've noticed that since I started using the pi hole some sites seem to have trouble with HTTPS on my desktop PC. Although I don't think it's a pi hole problem since it's working without a problem on my Chromebook which uses the exact same browser extensions as my primary PC.

Twitter for example

[image: Twitter with the Pi hole]

The chain seems to be OK

[image: Cert chain]

The first thing I checked was the console but it only says that it couldn't load the HTTPS versions of some trackers and analytics which is fine because the Pi doesn't listen on Port 443.

[image: console warnings]

I even installed [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) ([recommended on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920206/how-can-you-tell-exactly-what-insecure-items-are-causing-a-browser-to-warn-about)) to check if there is unencrypted data transferred from twitter.com or the Pi but noting is unencrypted

[image: Fiddler screenshot]

And here is where it gets really odd: Chrome is the only browser that has a problem (IE and Edge are having no such warnings) and most HTTPS sites are working just fine with Chrome.

### Sites with the error

- Twitter
- My online banking
- Sofortüberweisung.de (online payment processing)

### Sites without the error

- Facebook
- Reddit
- most other sites

Yes I already checked for malicious browser extensions or viruses on the Device

Has anyone of you experienced a similar problem or know a way where I can find what's bugging Chrome?

Comment: What's it say when you click on the cert? Are you sure it's insecure elements and not some other security issue? You could also try downloading Chrome Canary which has a very helpful new security tab in Developer tools to explain security errors.

Comment: The cert looks fine, the chain is also in tact. What's also weird is that the page loads instantly and without the "this page is insecure, click Advanced->continue". It just loads the site and shows the red https icon. Will try with canary

Comment: Yes but if you click on the red icon it should give you some indication why it's red (e.g. Insecure content). Though new security tab in Canary with give more detail (e.g. which content is insecure).

Comment: Interesting, Canary doesn't show the red https symbol but it's gray and when I click it, it says ERR_CERT_UNABLE_TO_CHECK_REVOCATION. So the browser can't check the certificate for some reason.

Google didn't help much because most posts regarding this error are from 2008 to 2011

Comment: Weird. That same reason on regular Chrome? Are only EV certs a problem (as Chrome doesn't check certs for OV and DV)? Anything else in security tab of Canary?

Comment: Regular Chrome didn't specify the reason but I guess it's the same problem. Canary doesn't have any other problems just that it can't verify if the cert has been revoked: (german windows) https://www.pictshare.net/c2fc8c5dc2.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Managed to figure this one out eventually after seeing same issue at work (behind a proxy).

For an EV certificate, as well as the usual checks (that the certificate matches the domain, has not expired, and links up to a CA certificate trusted by the computer), Chrome also insists on a live check that the certificate hasn't been revoked. This is done though a process called CRL or OCSP but basically requires a network call to the cert provider to allow this to happen.

Twitter, most online banks and www.sofort.com all use EV certs so require these checks.
Facebook, Reddit and most other sites do not use EV certs so do don't need these checks.

Now you'd like to think that the CRL/OCSP check would use the same proxy as used for internet browsing through the web browser but turns out this is not the case and a separate process called WinHTTP is used for that and this has a different proxy setting.

You can run the below command in a DOS prompt and I'm guessing it will show no proxy:

```
C:\>netsh winhttp show proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).
```

If so, and you've no longer direct access to the internet, except via your proxy then you should be able to set that using this command (assuming your proxy runs on port 8080 on proxyserver):

```
C:\>netsh winhttp set proxy proxyserver:8080

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Proxy Server(s) :  proxyserver:8080
    Bypass List     :  (none)
```

And then it should work. I couldn't get this to work as we use an authenticated proxy and it's a bit more complicated here but in theory it should work.

To reset this use the following:

```
C:\>netsh winhttp reset proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).
```

Now there's a question as to whether it should show this as red, insecure and, to me, it definitely shouldn't show that confusing "insecure content" message as that's wrong. Looks like Chrome Canary has improved the messaging around this, so hopefully that will make it into the main relase now. Though it still shows it as grey (i.e. worse than non-EV) which is arguable as to whether that's right or not.

More detail here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=583021