# Why does an SSL link get a mixed content error?

Tags: https, mixed-content

We have an SSL content management (vendor) site that is embedded in salesforce via iframe.  The vendor has permalinks for a certain subset of pages.  We simply have the full link https://test.com/portals/default.asp?perm=2421.  Very simple... User clicks on it in Chrome or FF... boom link doesn't work and spits out the mixed content error below.  I know this is a vendor issue but how can a browser detect it is going to an http page when the link is https and the final page they would be take to is https?

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://na2.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=01r400000001jzz&…15MHlOVlF4TmpveU1Eb3lNQzR5TlRSYSwxSTVmT0xTdzlpNTQ0c2FTTWdWT1JqLFlXWmtNR0po'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://test.com/portals/default.asp'. This request has been blocked;
>   the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

You are on an https webpage ( https://na2.salesforce.com ) and try to load an http ressource ( 'http://test.com/portals/default.asp ).

Most browser block it for security reason (even if the http request will redirect to https).

Comment: No I am loading - https://test.com/portals/default.asp?perm=2421 - wondering why current browser cares how it is getting parsed.

Comment: could you eventually provide the real url to check it?

Comment: It is behind SSO so you wouldn't be able to get to it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920206/how-can-you-tell-exactly-what-insecure-items-are-causing-a-browser-to-warn-about may help you find the root problem