# Mixed Content error when loading subdomain using SSL

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, subdomain

I'm having subdomain issues. When I visit my subdomain or any of its resources using "https" (https://requests.fortgordon.com/login), I get a 404 error with all of my pages resources failing to return due to "Mixed Content".

But when I visit the page using "http" (http://requests.fortgordon.com/login), it loads fine.

If I visit the subfolder directly using "https" (https://www.fortgordon.com/testrequest2/login) the page loads, but all the resources fail to load.

Also, I'm not sure if this helps explain the issue, but www.fortgordon.com is a Wordpress site and requests.fortgordon.com is not. Also, all links to my resources begin with "//" so that they can choose either "http" or "https" depending on the current page.

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to find out which resources cause this mixed content problem. Thus I consider it a duplicate of [How can you tell exactly what insecure items are causing a browser to warn about mixed secure and insecure items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920206/how-can-you-tell-exactly-what-insecure-items-are-causing-a-browser-to-warn-about)

Comment: Not exactly. I'm trying to find out why an https page is loading my resources as http even though they are written as "//subdomain.domain.com/style.css". On my parent domain, using the preceding "//" allows the resource to pick up the protocol used by the active page.

Comment: Your question is a bit light on these details. So you did already found out for sure which resource exactly is the problem and you've verified that you include exactly this resource always (even in dynamically generated code) in a protocol-independent way? If this is the case then maybe you add these details to your question and also the URL where others can reproduce the problem - because I doubt that without this anybody will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll update my question.

Comment: just because your ssl certificate covers your domain doesn;t mean it covers all it;s subdomains.. you may need to check on that...

Comment: I just purchased a wildcard SSL Certificate, so they should all be covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was. I needed to add a virtual host record through WHM. I logged in to WHM, clicked on **SSL/TLS** > **Install an SSL Certificate on a Domain**. In the domain box I typed in the subdomain I wanted covered, then clicked autofill by domain and install at the bottom – that added a virtualhost record for the subdomain with SSL. Now everything is working great!

Answer (score 1):

You include resources dynamically using JavaScript in your page and these resources are explicitly using `http://`. From `

```
... window._wpemojiSettings = ...
{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/www.fortgordon.com\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.5"}};
```

Also there are several stylesheets which gets loaded with explicit `http://`, like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='widget-calendar-pro-style-css'  href='http://www.fortgordon.com/wp-content/plugins/events-calendar-pro/src/resources/css/widget-calendar-full.css?ver=4.1.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

And then there are probably ads:

```
<aside id="sam_pro_place_widget-9" class="widget sam_pro_place_widget">
<div id='c2262_5_1' class='sam-pro-container sam-pro-place'>
<a id='ad-5-2262' class='sam-pro-ad' 
   href='http://www.ihg.com/armyhotels/hotels/us/en/reservation?cm_mmc=IMMerch-_-MA_US_en-_-fortgordon-_-externalsite' ...
```

The console in the Chrome browser will report these as mixed content when it tries to include these. It will also show you in the 'Sources' view where loading these resources comes from.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this; unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. All of the resources you're referring too are coming from the 404 error page. Perhaps looking into the other link will help make more sense of my situation. If you visit https://www.fortgordon.com/testrequest2/login (which is where my subdomain points), you'll see that all the resources that are using the subdomain are returning 404 errors. But this only happens when I visit this page with "https".

Comment: @Nate: In this case the main problem is not the Mixed Content but the 404. And 404 means file not found which means that it is a problem with the servers configuration. Thus if you want to get help with this problem you have to provide the server configuration.