# Mixed content error in chrome; Site contains no mixed content; Clearing Cache and reopening Chrome does not solve

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, web-development-server

I am getting a mixed content warning from Google Chrome.  It does not show in Firefox or Explorer.

I'm opening the site from a test server on localhost running Vista, Apache2.2.16, mod_ssl2.2.16, OpenSSL0.9.8, and PHP5.3.3.  All content is forced through https by apache.  I am using a self-signed certificate.

The entire source code is contained in index.html.  It reads:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>    
 <h1>Hello</h1>
</html>
```

First, I verified with ctrl-shift-j that there is no mixed content.  Then, I tried, in varying combinations, closing Chrome and reopening, clearing the cache, and restarting the server.

Can someone please tell me how to get rid of the warning? Thanks, Jimbo

Comment: Are you including stylesheets or scripts from a non https source? How about images?

Comment: Is this the exact document you're sending to the browser?  Because it's not well formed. A well formed HTML doc must have a head and a body, and the head must contain a title.  As it's XHTML, you may also need the XML preamble too.  As for your actual problem, well the doctype URL is obviously an external source.  Does Chrome attempt to download DTDs for anything?

Comment: This is the exact document.  I know that it is not well formed. I made it quickly for the specific purpose of solving this problem. I have since removed the doctype tag. The effect is still the same. I am not including any stylesheets, scripts, or images.

Answer (score 0):

I tried accessing the site through https://127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and it worked without a mixed-content warning. I don't understand why the error occurs, but I'm pretty sure this won't be an issue when the site is actually published. Thanks all. --Jimbo

Answer (score 0):

This is just theory for now, but I am finding that I get the "mixed content" warning in Chrome even when there is no mixed content, if *sometime* during the session mixed content was already encountered on the domain.

(Also mentioned here: [Why is Chrome reporting a secure / non secure warning when no other browsers aren't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087591/why-is-chrome-reporting-a-secure-non-secure-warning-when-no-other-browsers-aren), and reported as a bug here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24152)