# How to fix the https "not secure" message in Chrome?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

My website is a WordPress based website located here: https://www.saintjohnscamp.org/. I cannot figure out how to fix the https "not secure" message that comes up when you view the site in Google Chrome, which reads: "Your connection to www.saintjohnscamp.org is encrypted using 256-bit encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not secure..." I have tried disabling all plugins in WordPress and looked at the source code of the page and cannot find any images, iframes, objects, etc. that are pulling from http:// instead of https://. The only instances of http:// in the source code are external links, which don't affect the not secure message (to the best of my knowledge). Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Is there a utility or service out there I can use to troubleshoot this message and fixing my page to be fully https compliant?

Comment: Open up the resource inspector, which will show exactly what is loaded from where.

Comment: Did you try removing all external http just to see what happens? Since you're using Chrome, perhaps set all insecure content to be blocked and see what breaks? I do see insecure content warnings from your flickr images.

Comment: It's all of your unsecured calls to flicker that's causing the issue. Everything else is using ssl. Apparently, and just tested, you can replace all of your `http` calls to flicker with `https`.

Comment: Thanks, I used the resource inspector to remove not only non secure calls to Flickr, but non secure calls to some Twitter scripts too. Now the inspector is not giving me any more non secure errors, but Chrome is still presenting the same non secure message. Arg, what could it be!?

Comment: Nevermind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087591/why-is-chrome-reporting-a-secure-non-secure-warning-when-no-other-browsers-aren

Comment: @YannRamin, That's not how the resource inspector works... A site can have hundreds of resources. It's not practically to manually review them all just to find one not using https or a relative protocol.

Comment: I've also noticed some browsers will cache this warning, even if the page doesn't actually load any non-http resources. I had this problem in Chrome, and confirmed with Wireshark that everything was loading over https, and the error only went away after I closed and restarted Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the request with Wireshark:

Close other browsers, open Wireshark, select Capture - Interfaces, and select Start on the active internet device. Then enter "http" in the top filter box, it will show current http requests and responses. You could also filter by port 80 (http) or 443 (https).

Wireshark shows the site is requesting http, not https, for:

platform.twitter.com/widgets.js?ver=1.1

twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js

api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne

and other twitter.com and flickr.com urls.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the Twitter and Flickr calls, but I'm still receiving the error. I don't know how to use Wireshark or else I would test myself. Are there any other http calls I'm missing?

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087591/why-is-chrome-reporting-a-secure-non-secure-warning-when-no-other-browsers-aren

Comment: To use Wireshark, just close other browsers, open Wireshark, select Capture - Interfaces, and select Start on the active internet device. Then enter "http" in the top filter box, it will show current http requests and responses.

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is that URL:

> https://lite.piclens.com/current/piclens_optimized.js

Piclens only offers this two versions:

- http://lite.piclens.com/current/piclens.js               full commented file         (~39KB)
- http://lite.piclens.com/current/piclens_optimized.js     lighter deployment file     (~21KB)

Piclens current SSL certificate has expired.

Comment: Why do you think this is his problem, this *is* a secured call.

Comment: @Peter This certificate has expired or is not yet valid. Piclens only offers HTTP links.

Comment: I have removed the link to Piclens and I'm still receiving the non secure message. Thanks for this tip though, that is very good to know.

Comment: This solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087591/why-is-chrome-reporting-a-secure-non-secure-warning-when-no-other-browsers-aren