# SSL warning being shown by chrome due to images on AWS S3

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, amazon-s3

So, I have bought a signed certicate and installed it properly on my server. But I have noticed that chrome is warning me that there are resources that are not secure. The problem is that I have images (jpg and png files) on a bucket on AWS S3. Is there a way to get rid of this warning or would I have to live with that?

What kind of files does chrome "complains" about (warns about) when they are not secure. Every kind of file (css, images, js, fonts, ...) that is shown in my webpage?

Comment: That's because they're being requested with http, not https.  Make sure your pages request all resources using an https://... URL.

Comment: This is the beautifully simple way to link to your s3 bucket via https... https://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/amazon-s3-gotcha-using-virtual-host.html#commentform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What kind of files does chrome "complains" about (warns about) when they are not secure. Every kind of file (css, images, js, fonts, ...) that is shown in my webpage?

All content can trigger the warning. Its not limited to a particular file type.

Mixing and matching secure and non-secure resources subjects the web app user to downgrade or stripping attacks.

> Is there a way to get rid of this warning or would I have to live with that?

Provide all the content securely and the warning will go away.

---

Also see:

- [Why is Chrome reporting a secure / non secure warning when no other browsers aren't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087591/why-is-chrome-reporting-a-secure-non-secure-warning-when-no-other-browsers-are)
- [Find out what resources are not going over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292697/find-out-what-resources-are-not-going-over-https)

And other stuff you might be interested in:

- [Software >> sslstrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/)
- [How does SSLstrip work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41988/how-does-sslstrip-work)
- [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)
- [Content Security Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy)
- [The State of HSTS Deployment:  A Survey and Common Pitfalls](https://garron.net/crypto/hsts/hsts-2013.pdf)
- [An empirical study of strict transport security and key pinning](http://jbonneau.com/doc/KB14-hsts_pinning_survey_working_draft.pdf)